Retreiving an old app
I created an app on Heroku years ago and then got a job. I'm looking to see if it's possible for them to retrieve that data and kick that project back on. When I log in to my dashboard, I don't see it there anymore, so I'm sure it's not possible. But thought I'd post the question here in case anyone has had some success with this.
Thanks!

It might depend on how you originally deployed it. If the app can no longer be found in the account heroku probably doesn't have it anymore. But if you deployed through the integration with github the app might still be on there.
